# How to draw a circle that's not perfectly circular in react native

Tags: react-native

I need to draw this half circle with a black border, but it's not a perfectly round circle. I can't use an Icon because it needs to be the same height on both phone and tablet and if I use an icon the height must change in order to fill the different widths. I've tried the method of creating a View and then giving the border radius 1/2 the measurement of the width but that give me a perfect circle. If I attempt to reduce the border radius I get more of a rectangle with rounded corners than a circle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the desired UI by absolutely positioning two big circles which looks like one uneven circle/ellipse. Check below code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

function UnevenCircle() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={styles.limeBackground}>

            </View>
            <View style={styles.firstBigCircle}>

            </View>
            <View style={styles.secondBigCircle}>

            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default UnevenCircle;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        position: 'relative',
    },
    limeBackground: {
        height: HEIGHT,
        width: WIDTH,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'limegreen'
    },
    firstBigCircle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: HEIGHT / 4,
        left: 0 - WIDTH / 2.3,
        height: HEIGHT,
        width: HEIGHT,
        borderRadius: HEIGHT * 2,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "#000"
    },
    secondBigCircle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backfaceVisibility: 'visible',
        height: HEIGHT,
        width: HEIGHT,
        top: 0 - HEIGHT / 3,
        left: 0 - WIDTH / 2.2,
        borderRadius: HEIGHT * 2,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "#000',"
    }
})
```

You can customize it as per your liking.

Happy coding :)